# Interesting behavior regarding Rails 'show' action on controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller, show

It seems like as long as a route matches 'somecontrollername#show', there is a view for it: somecontrollername/show.html, and the controller is defined without the show action, a get request to the route automatically renders the show view.

Can somebody please explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Rails work. If they have route for specific action, but this action is not implemented in appropriate controller, they try to render template named the same way as action. If they can't find this template, they throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

You will have a resource route that automatically routes to a template show action like so:

```
resources :applicants # Controller for this resource can automatically serve REST requests
```

To remove it, in your route add `except: [:show]`

```
resources :applicants, :except => [:show]
```

Comment: I'll have one even if I don't have 'resources :somecontrollername' in my routes file?